# Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) interface language (hl) on a multi-language site

Tags: multilingual, google-custom-search

I am implementing a google search engine on a multilanguage website.
It seems the language of CSE is based on the user's browser preferences.

What I would expect instead is that when a user is browing the english version of the site, I would see the search engine in english (hl=en), when in german I would expect hl=de.

Is there anyway I can force that, based on the locale of the website?